# Shuffle rows of a large csv

Tags: python, csv, random, shuffle

I want to shuffle this dataset to have a random set. It has 1.6 million rows but the first are 0 and the last 4, so I need pick samples randomly to have more than one class. The actual code prints only class 0 (meaning in just 1 class). I took advice from this platform but doesn't work.

```
fid = open("sentiment_train.csv", "r")

li = fid.readlines(16000000)


random.shuffle(li)

fid2 = open("shuffled_train.csv", "w")

fid2.writelines(li)

fid2.close()

fid.close()

sentiment_onefourty_train = pd.read_csv('shuffled_train.csv', header= 0, delimiter=",", usecols=[0,5], nrows=100000)

sentiment_onefourty_train.columns=['target', 'text']

print(sentiment_onefourty_train['target'].value_counts())
```

Comment: Note, the number you are passing to `readlines` is a limit on the *total bytes/characters* to read, not the number of lines. You probably shouldn't be using `readlines` anyway, just use the file object as an iterator directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you read in your data using Pandas, you can also do the randomisation in a different way using [`pd.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```py
df = pd.read_csv('sentiment_train.csv', header= 0, delimiter=",", usecols=[0,5])
df.columns=['target', 'text']
df1 = df.sample(n=100000)
```

If this fails, it might be good to check out the amount of unique values and how frequent they appear. If the first 1,599,999 are 0 and the last is only 4, then the chances are that you won't get any 4.

Comment: I just tried that way but it's still not randomizing the dataset.

Comment: Then it might be a good idea to check the amount of occurrences of each `target` column in your dataset. I fear you have a very unbalanced dataset. What is the outcome of `df['target'].value_counts()`?

Comment: The total dataset has 1.6 million rows, so that's why I limited to 100000 because it exceeds the limit. Therefore, the output is 100000.

Comment: I fully understand that your dataset is 1.6 million rows. I'm not sure which limit you are referring to. I could generate a dataset of 1.6 million rows and still show the counts of the values in `target` even if there are 1.6 million unique values in there.

Comment: I mean this: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 232719-232720: invalid continuation byte"

Comment: In that case, you unfortunately have to fix the file you are reading (or change the encoding using `encoding='find your encoding'`, or ignore them when reading in using `encoding_errors='ignore'`). For the part that you *CAN* read, what is the distribution of values of `target`? If there is only one value, then you know your answer too.

Comment: Yes! encoding helped me! Thanks! Btw, it has two classes.